# lein and lein-test-out plugin

Tags: junit, clojure, leiningen

I would to like use lein-test-out plugin from https://github.com/arohner/lein-test-out/ or from https://clojars.org/org.clojars.jaley/lein-test-out

But when I use [lein-test-out "0.1.0"] in dev-dependecty nothing heppens, when I use

> :profiles {:dev {
>       :dependencies [[junit/junit "4.10"]
>                      [lein/test-out "0.2.0"]]
>       :plugins [[lein-test-out "0.2.0"]]

I have get:
leiningen.test-out  Problem loading: Could not locate clojure/contrib/find_namespaces__init.class or clojure/contrib/find_namespaces.clj on classpath:

Full project.clj:

```
(defproject dataserver "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
:aot                [#"a\.b\..*"]
:omit-source         true
:warn-on-reflection  true
:min-lein-version    "2.0.0"
:source-paths       ["src-clj"]
:resource-paths     ["/home/storm/storm/conf/storm.yaml" "resources"]
:uberjar-name        "b.jar"
:uberjar-exclusions [#"log4j.properties"]
:main         a.b.repl
:ring         {:handler a.b.topmanager.core/app}
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
             [org.clojure/data.json "0.1.3"]
             [org.clojure/data.priority-map "0.0.1"]
             [com.rabbitmq/amqp-client "2.8.4"]
             [org.scribe/scribe "1.3.1"]
             [http.async.client "0.4.5"]
             [org.clojure/tools.logging "0.2.4"]
             [clj-redis "0.0.12"]]
:profiles {:dev {
:dependencies [[storm "0.7.3" :exclusions [org.clojure/tools.loggin org.clojure/tools.cli  compojure  hiccup
                                            ring/ring-jetty-adapter  backtype/jzmq]]
               [org.clojure/data.xml "0.0.6"]
               [org.clojure/data.zip "0.1.1"]
               [compojure "1.0.4"]
               [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.1.1"]
               [org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 "1.6.6"]
               [junit/junit "4.10"]
               [org.clojars.jaley/lein-test-out "0.1.1-SNAPSHOT"]]                                                                                               
:plugins [[lein-ring "0.6.7"]
          [lein-test-out "0.1.1"]]
}}  
:jvm-opts     ["-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
             "-Dstorm.jar=target/b.jar"]
:repl-options {:timeout 60000})
```

Answer (score 0):

lein-test-out seems to expect `clojure.contrib.find-namespaces` from `clojure.contrib`. You could try adding `clojure.contrib` 1.2 to your dependencies, but keep in mind that clojure.contrib is not fully compatible with clojure 1.3 and up while `lein-test-out` itself requires 1.3, so it looks like if you need something reliable, you would either fix it yourself, get someone else to fix it for you or not use `lein-test-out`.